# Scrollview of tweetdeck

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview

I am busy with an application and I want to implement a scrollview like the tweetdeck application.

You can zoom in en out UITableviews within an UIScrollview.

I was wondering how they did that. What I can imagine is that there are two UIScrollviews.
This because of the zoom in and out of one item in the UIScrollview.

What I don't understand is how the animation precise work and how they zoom out the UITableView.
I was wondering if someone can help me to get in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

Actually a UITableView is a UIScrollView, so if you add some code like following, you will be able to zoom your table view.

```
self.tableView.maximumZoomScale = 2.0;
self.tableView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
```

And a UIScrollView delegate method

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return self.tableView;
}
```

Comment: I do know that a UITableview is a UIScrollview but somehow I didn't do anything with that fact. What I used now is transform  = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.75, 0.75f); I now only need to luck at the interaction part with zooming in when you click on the view